# Screechy feedback on audio with getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia

First attempts at getUserMedia, using the most basic sample code:

```
<video autoplay></video>

<script>
    var errorCallback = function (e) {
        console.log('Reeeejected!', e);
    };

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||   navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, function (localMediaStream) {
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);

    }, errorCallback);
</script>
```

This results in instant screeching feedback coming out the speakers...

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is your  tag playing the sound (on your speakers) being captured by your mic, creating the screeching feedback.

To fix it, add the muted attribute like this:

Only remember to not add this attribute if you ever add other video tags for remote streams.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your video element like:

`id="cameraID"`

then add the following to your code:

`document.getElementById("cameraID").muted = true;`